# mysql_real_escape_string and apostrophe problem

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, mysql-real-escape-string, apostrophe

so I've been using mysql_real_escape_string  to insert data into my database...but then when I do that it replaces all apostrophes with the symbol â€™

so instead of display it's, it's displaying itâ€™s.......

is there a way to reconvert those â€™'s into apostrophes when I read back from the database?

Comment: What character encoding do you use for your output? And did your [specify it properly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some character encoding issue in some way.

Because in UTF-8, `’` (U+2019) is encoded with 0xE28099. And that represents the characters `â` (0xE2), `€` (0x80), and `™` (0x99) in [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

So it seems that you just forgot to [specify your output character encoding properly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2.2) so that the browser uses its default character encoding Windows-1252 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Apply [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) to UTF-8 in your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your database and application are using the same character encoding.

In binary, `'` is identical in value to `â€™`, so you need to ensure the encoding is set the same.

In your PHP application, you can specify this with the following two lines.

```
define(‘DB_CHARSET’, ‘utf8′);
define(‘DB_COLLATE’, ”);
```

This sets your application to use UTF-8 character set, which you must ensure matches your database's collation, then your problem will go away.

You can programatically change the database character set with the `mysql_set_charset` function.

Comment: I believe those constants are wordpress specific not general PHP.

Comment: No, `'` (U+0027) is 0x27 in UTF-8. But `’` (U+2019) is 0xE28099 in UTF-8 and that represents the characters `â`, `€`, and `™` in [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).